# Norton equivalent in sinusoidal RC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, norton

[image]

I've been able to compute Iab, which is easy enough since the circuit short circuits when you connect A-B, but I couldn't find Req / Yeq.

I'm analyzing the circuit as ((R1//R2)+C1)//C2). Is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm analyzing the circuit as ((R1//R2)+C1)//C2)

This formula will give you the impedance of the circuit (\$Z_{eq}\$).

For the admittance just take the inverse (\$Y_{eq}=1/Z_{eq}\$).

Or do the calculation using admittance from the start

$$Y_{eq} = Y_{C2} + \frac{Y_{C1}(G_1+G_2)}{Y_{C1}+G_1+G_2}$$

where \$G_1\$ and \$G_2\$ are the conductances of R1 and R2, and \$Y_{C1}\$ and \$Y_{C2}\$ are the admittances of C1 and C2.

Comment: Thank you. When I plug in the numbers, it doesn't match with the solution. Maybe I'm just too tired and doing an error in computing idk.

Comment: @BigggieBigs, you haven't shared your work, so we can't see what kind of error you might have made.

Answer (score 0):

For phasors, \$I=I_{_0}\cos\left(\phi\right)\$. But the problem used sine, not cosine. I would first convert to cosine. For that, subtract \$90^\circ\$ to get to a cosine and because (for power reasoning) current is conjugate to voltage, it is \$180^\circ\$ out of phase. So \$\phi=120^\circ-90^\circ\pm 180^\circ\$ (whichever is less than \$180^\circ\$.) In this case, \$\phi=-150^\circ\$. So \$I=2\cdot\left[\cos\left(-150^\circ\right)+j\sin\left(-150^\circ\right)\right]=-\sqrt{3}-j\$. Which appears to be what the solution says.

As far as the admittance goes, it really is just the reciprocal of impedance. And you were right to calculate impedance the way you did. I agree with it.

Here's what my calculator said (after I set \$\omega=2\$) when I typed in `1/(((3|2)+1F)|3F)`:

$$0.710059172 + j6.29585799, 6.33577239\: \angle\: 83.5652608^\circ$$

So I think you are fine with your approach. You know how to compute the impedance. And the admittance is just the reciprocal of it. That's all.

To turn \$\frac{c}{a+bi}\$ into \$a^{'}+b^{'}i\$ just follows a process:\$\frac{c}{a+bi}\cdot\frac{a-bi}{a-bi}=c\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}-c\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}i\$. In this case, the impedance you should compute from `((3|2)+1F)|3F` is \$0.0176886792 - j0.156839623\$. So the admittance is then just \$\frac{0.0176886792}{0.0176886792^2+0.156839623^2}-\frac{0.156839623}{0.0176886792^2+0.156839623^2}i\$. And that does get you the right result.